# How can I programmatically determine the sampling rate and bitrate of a WAV file?

Tags: python, wav, vosk

There is a program written in python which recognizes text with the vosk library used. To recognize text you need to pass the sampling rate and the language model with this line : KaldiRecognizer(model, 96000), where 96000 is the frequency itself. to define the sampling rate of the file I use the following code

```
with wave.open(r'a.wav', 'rb') as wave_file:
    frame_rate = wave_file.getframerate()
    print(frame_rate)
```

BUT! Virtually all of the files it determines the frequency: 48000, for some audio files, it is somehow not suitable and is displayed some nonsense and not the text (just a set of words), that is, vosk does not properly determine the text in audio, this problem is solved by replacing the frequency manual to the right, always need to select it. what could be the problem? before that, converted an audio file in online conversion. I would like to automate the process.

I tried converting an audio file with a pre-recorded sampling rate:

```
audio_file = 'a.wav'
y, sr = librosa.load(audio_file, sr=48000)
```

Comment: Do you have an example of an incorrectly-detected file you can post somewhere we can download it? It'd be helpful to see if that file has a header on it.

Comment: BTW, 48kHz is pretty much standard in the TV industry, so if that's where you're getting your samples it's what I'd expect to see.

Comment: Charles Duffy,  yes, there is, but it is in Russian

Comment: For purposes of checking the header, the language isn't important.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/198Y75EZf1CFO4sVGWAajwXi0hVgGafcG?usp=sharing

Comment: Assuming you're the owner of that share, you should have a request to provide access.

Comment: can you try again?

Comment: Okay, that file has a header on it that claims to be a 48kHz audio file, so the software isn't wrong to detect it that way. Do you know how the file was created?

Comment: (for folks following along at home, the output from libmagic / the `file` utility is `a.wav: RIFF (little-endian) data, WAVE audio, Microsoft PCM, 16 bit, stereo 48000 Hz`)

Comment: (`soxi`, a built-to-purpose tool, agrees with libmagic on all the details above)

Comment: The audio was recorded through obs studio,
Then I wanted to take the text from it, but it gave me an error
I had to convert the file through the website

Comment: ...so at this point, I'd stop focusing on figuring out why the software loading the file is detecting its sampling rate incorrectly, and start focusing on why the software _creating_ the file recorded its sampling rate incorrectly -- assuming the sampling rate really is incorrect; I haven't actually inspected the file contents to see if it has waveforms that are at frequencies &c typical for human speech when interpreted per that stated 48kHz sampling rate.

Comment: Ah. OBS Studio _is_ an AV tool, so 48kHz makes a lot of sense for it to use as a default; that _is_ the usual sampling rate used in that field.

Comment: is there any way I can change the audio with a specified frequency in python?

Comment: So, the question is if the header is wrong (claiming 48kHz when the data is really 96kHz) and you just want to rewrite the header but leave the data the same; or if the data _really is_ 48kHz and you need to resample it to convert to 96kHz cleanly. To actually resample the audio, the tool I'd reach for first (because I know it and it's been around forever, not necessarily because it's the best for the job) is [sox](https://pysox.readthedocs.io/). To just change the numbers in the header without any resampling, the standard `wave` library is good enough; just copy the raw frames across.